# SQL order by date descending expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, Worker and Worker_Balance:

```
---------------           ------------------
|  Worker     |           | Worker_Balance |
|-------------|<----------|----------------|
|             |           | INT workerBID  |
| ...         |           | INT amount     |
---------------           | INT workerID   |
                          | DATE timestamp |
                          ------------------
```

and the following sql-query:

```
SELECT Worker.ID, Worker.xy, SUM(Worker_Balance.amount)
FROM Worker
JOIN Worker_Balance ON WorkerBalance.workerID = Worker.workerID
GROUP BY Worker.ID, Worker.xy
```

i need the results ordered by the latest timestamp, but the the oldest must be first. So the Worker, where the last transaction is the oldest, comes first.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause too.

Comment: When GROUP BY, only selected columns may be included in the ORDER BY.

Comment: Also tell which is SQL engine (MS SQL, MySQL, Postgre SQL)

Comment: thanks, i forgot the GROUP BY clause

Comment: So, when you forgot, then edit the question @Leander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in order to aggregate and [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) in order to sort:

```
SELECT Worker.ID
    ,Worker.xy
    ,MAX(Worker.TIMESTAMP) last_transaction
    ,SUM(Worker_Balance.amount)
FROM Worker
JOIN Worker_Balance ON WorkerBalance.workerID = Worker.workerID
GROUP BY Worker.ID
    ,Worker.xy
ORDER BY last_transaction
```

Comment: And MAX ;) that was the missing link, it's actually a pretty simple solution, thank you!